# GWT: Trying to save a file in server side

Tags: tomcat

I have this method in my server side which saves a new excel file in my war folder.

But when i run the same code from my tomcat ,It does not save the file anywhere ,

I expect it to save the file in my project folder in webapps
here:

E:\tomcat 7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\foodchain

But its not saving it there..

Please guide me where I am wrong. 
Where the file get saved when running on localhost.

Code:

```
    public String exportToExcel(ArrayList<ExcelDataDTO> excelDataList) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(".\\images\\report.xls");//"D:\\POI111.xls"
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Orders Worksheet");
        for(int i=0; i< excelDataList.size(); i ++){
        HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);
        row1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getChain());
        row1.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getOrder());
        row1.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getShop());
        row1.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getCustomerAddress());
        row1.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getCar());
        row1.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(excelDataList.get(i).getLoaded());
        }
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.flush();
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "exported";
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the Tomcat working directory? It should be under `$TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina/`

Comment: thanks , I am looking here : E:\tomcat 7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\work\Catalina\localhost\foodchain....  But its not here

Answer (score 0):

The "current" directory can vary depending on the environment, so you should not rely on it. Inside a servlet method, you can use this code to retrieve the absolute file path of the webapp root:

```
String rootDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

In your case it should return: `E:\tomcat 7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\foodchain\`

Use it to build the path to the xls file and you should be good.